# Affecting all instances of a GameObject at once

Tags: unity, c#, instancing

I want all instances of a prefab to change their velocity when one of them is clicked, and I think having each object constantly check a variable with a coroutine might not be the best solution. How can I reference all instances of the prefab in a script efficiently?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Gather the instances into a collection as you instantiate them. Then you can iterate over all members of the collection anytime you want, with no search overhead.

```
public class MyType : MonoBehaviour {

    static List<MyType> allOfMyType = new List<MyType();

    void Awake() {
        allOfMyType.Add(this);
    }

    void OnDestroy() {
        allOfMyType.Remove(this);
    }

    public void DoSomethingToAllOfUs() {
        foreach(var instance in allOfMyType)
            DoSomethingTo(instance);
    }
}
```